# How to find the frequency of the most frequent value (mode) of a series in polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "tags": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d"] 
})
```

This is how to compute the most frequent element of the column using the `.mode` expression:

```py
df.select([
    pl.col("tags").mode().alias("mode"),
])
```

How can I display also the frequency/count of that mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `value_counts` expression. This expression will return a `Struct` datatype where the first field is the unique value and the second field is the count of that value.

```py
df.select([
    pl.col("tags").value_counts()
])
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ tags      │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"c",4}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"a",3}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"b",1}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"d",1}   │
└───────────┘
```

Or if you want to have that result as a `DataFrame`:

```py
(df.select([
    pl.col("tags").value_counts()
]).to_series().struct.to_frame())
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬────────┐
│ tags ┆ counts │
│ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ u32    │
╞══════╪════════╡
│ c    ┆ 4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a    ┆ 3      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ d    ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b    ┆ 1      │
└──────┴────────┘
```

**Edited:**
Which can be even simpler:

```py
df["tags"].value_counts()
```

Comment: Nice, somehow I thought Polars did not have a `value_counts` method. `df["tags"].value_counts()` returns the same as your second example though, which is easier

Answer (score 0):

I found this method, but I'm not sure if there's a better way:

```py
df.select([
    pl.col("tags").mode().alias("mode"),
    pl.col("tags").filter(pl.col("tags") == pl.col("tags").mode()).count().alias("count")
])
```

Output:

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ mode ┆ count │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ u32   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ c    ┆ 4     │
└──────┴───────┘
```